# My for loop runs only once while trying to reverse an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```js
var amount = Number(window.prompt("number of elements"));
var list = []
for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++); {
  list.push(window.prompt("enter elements of the list"));
}
list.reverse();
document.write(list);
```

I tried to reverse a list but whatever amount I enter my code only runs trough for loop once, asks me for element of the list and ends the for loop and prints out my one and only entry since the for loop doesn't ask me for elements multiple times. I'm a beginner it's a silly mistake probably but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: You have an extra `;` after `for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++)`

Comment: That creates an empty loop body, so the prompt isn't inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar pointed out the problem is due to a logic error.

```js
/* Read the item from the prompt until you and write it to the list container. */
function read(list, size){
  for(let i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
    list.push(window.prompt());
}

/* Print a list container */
function print(list){
   for(let i = 0 ; i < list.length ; ++i)
    console.log(list[i]);
}

var list = []
read(list, Number(window.prompt("number of elements")));
list.reverse();
print(list);
```